# Jekyll: is there a plugin or way to embed a github file as code

Tags: plugins, jekyll

I want to be able to provide a link to a file on github similar to the jekyll-gist plugin but for github repository files.

I was hoping for something similar to jekyll-gist so that all i need to do is have something simple like below example which will then show the file as code:

```
{% github https://raw.github.com/myrepo/myfile.py %}
```

then it would just render that file as code